# Scheduled ffmpeg function gives thread.error and also fires ffmpeg too many times

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to record a clip of a radio stream every hour. Below is the code I am using to accomplish this so far.

```
    def sched(): # schedules a recording every hour
        def stream_record ():
            timeinfo = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S%f')
            ffmpegEXE = "C:/path/to/ffmpeg.exe" 
            subprocess.call([ffmpegEXE, '-i', url, '-t', '00:07:00', 
            output_folder + timeinfo + '_' + str(start_minute) + 'url.mp3'], shell=True)

        i = 0
        while True:

        x = datetime.today()
        y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=i, minute= start_minute, second=0, microsecond=0) 
        i = (i + 1) % 24
        delta_t=y-x
        secs=delta_t.seconds+1
        t = Timer(secs,stream_record)
        t.start()

sched()
```

Two things go wrong. (1) It will run, however an error reads:

> line X in (module)
>
> > sched()
>
> line Y in sched
>
> > t.start()
>
> line Z in start
>
> > _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
> >
> > thread.error: can't start new thread

And (2) when it runs, ffmpeg will initialize a recording anywhere from 5-15 times, saving many clips when I only want it to save one.

How do I fix these errors and get ffmpeg to connect and record only one clip every hour?

I know this is an issue with the scheduling function; the ffmpeg command works fine, as does the python script calling it.